# How to make an instance of a file and progress reading bar

Tags: java, swing

[image]

Hello everyone this my first project in java swing and seems complex which am still pushing to get it done, am trying to insert a code in which when I click "PAC file it will open" for me to load the file and also when I click Flash the progress bar will start Loading the file when the mobile device is connected.

Please this is a desktop Application for installation of stock ROM on mobile in .PAC format for Thanks ☺☺

Answer (score 0):

I put together something like this back in the day:

https://sourceforge.net/p/tus/code/HEAD/tree/tjacobs/ui/ex/ProgressBarForDataFetching.java

https://sourceforge.net/p/tus/code/HEAD/tree/tjacobs/io/DataFetcher.java

As I recall, the two biggest issues are

A. How much data (in bytes) are you downloading? If you don't know, it's impossible to measure where you are in the download
B. How quickly does the data get there? So for instance, I believe I found that a progress bar wasn't really helpful when reading files from the local FS because it's over so fast